# Read from pipes and socket simultaneously

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winapi, asynchronous

I need to translate some POSIX code to Windows, but I am having trouble when it comes to asynchronous IO. On POSIX, we used `select` to determine whether data was available either at one of multiple pipes or at a socket.

We are setting `HANDLE`s for the pipes of a child process like this:

```
ZeroMemory(&startInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
startInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
startInfo.hStdInput = hInRead;
startInfo.hStdOutput = hOutWrite;
startInfo.hStdError = hErrWrite;
startInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
```

We can read from stdout and stderr using the `HANDLE`s `hOutRead` and `hErrRead`. However, we need to figure out which of these streams has data available.

Additionally, there is a socket involved and we need to read data from that socket as well. We create the socket as usual like this (error handling skipped):

```
s = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
connect(s, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
```

and receive data using `recv`, but synchronously.

How can we read data from all three streams simultaneously? Currently, we use `CreateThread` to have one thread per stream, but we figured this is pretty inefficient. Is there a native way to do this on Windows?

Comment: native way in windows - bind pipe/sockets to iocp.encapsulate every handle in some class. for every i/o your *OVERLAPPED* must be part of some structure which containing back pointer to class containing pipe/socket handle. so when i/o operation is finished - you got back pointer to your  *OVERLAPPED*, cast  it to your structure and got pointer to class containing handle

Comment: Simultanously is just a point of view. If you want to make it as much parallel as possible you've to use three different threads ( it also depends on your hardware). By the way you can just check them in a while with just one thread. It depends on how much operations (and the reactivity) you will perform on them.

Comment: @BetaRunner - count of threads must depend only from cpu core count, but not from handle count doing async i/o not thread per handle, but one common, generic thread pool listening to iocp. and we can use system default thread pool - so not create any threads yourself at all

Comment: and you not need 2(or 3) separate pipes for comunicate with child process. one pipe pair (with read/write access) is enough

Comment: @RbMm what I mean is if you've X physical threads and a program with Y threads, Y > X, you maximum level of parallelism is X.

Comment: @RbMm "encapsulate every handle in some class": We are using plain C, no C++ extensions. "and you not need 2(or 3) separate pipes for comunicate with child process": We cannot modify the executable which is the child process, so we cannot build any communication except stdin, stdout and stderr into the child process. AFAIK, this requires three pipes.

Comment: @BetaRunner That's why we would like to avoid threads. How would you check both the pipes and the socket in a loop?

Comment: @BetaRunner - no this is mistake. the count of threads absolute in depended from count of parallel asynchronous operation.  `Y > X` - absolute not need. we can handle with single working thread - any count of asynchronous i/o

Comment: @just.me - you and not need modify child. you need create only one pipe pair. one handle in parent process and one inherit pipe handle passed to child process. and you need set all 3 `startInfo.hStd*` fields to this handle. and this will nice work. so you not need 3 handles. one read/write pipe in parent and one connected to him in child. i many time do this

Comment: `We are using plain C, no C++ extensions` - of course in *c++* more easy write class/structs. but `struct` exist in *c* too. so no problem do this in *c* also. simply little more src code compare c++.

Comment: so must be `hStdInput == hStdError == hStdOutput;` and all set to single pipe wich created with read/write access - and this is enough and nice worked

Comment: @RbMm We need to handle data written to stdout and stderr separately, so we cannot use a single pipe.

Comment: @BetaRunner How could I check both the pipes and the socket in a loop?

Comment: `How could I check both the pipes and the socket in a loop?`- if you ask about native and most efficient for windows solution - you not need any loops at all. you need callbacks. use `BindIoCompletionCallback` for your sockets/pipes. or `CreateThreadpoolIo `

Comment: @RbMm How can I convert a `SOCKET` to a `HANDLE` for `BindIoCompletionCallback`?

Comment: by reinterpret cast `(HANDLE)s` - socket really handle. so `BindIoCompletionCallback` and `CreateThreadpoolIo` (from vista) nice worked with socket handles

Comment: Pragmatically, unless you have a significant number of child processes running simultaneously (more than two or three, say) you might as well keep using separate threads.  The modest performance gains from doing it more cleverly are unlikely to justify the effort involved.